# How to add shortcut onto Wine desktop?

Tags: wine

Wine has a "desktop mode" where it renders a virtual desktop in a window and renders all its windows within that desktop. You can access it through:

```
wine explorer /desktop=arbname,1920x1200 "C:\...\...\application.exe"
```

I used it and some applications have installed icons on the virtual desktop:

[image]

Those shortcuts (`.lnk` files) are located in `~/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Desktop/`, but are binary files.

How can I create a custom one?

**Note:** I am *not* asking how to create a shortcut to a Wine app on my Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: good question - does any of the suggestions here work under wine? http://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd

Answer (score 5):

With an amount of pain and suffering, fossfreedom's [suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd) paid off. I didn't try the VBScript method, mainly because I didn't know how much of that is actually implemented in Wine. There was also mention of add-on packs that don't seem to be present in Wine.

So that left me with [the Shortcut.exe method](https://superuser.com/a/392066/30127) from [alfasin](https://superuser.com/users/117980/alfasin).

1. [Download Shortcut.exe from its creator](http://optimumx.com/downloads.html#Shortcut)
2. Unzip it and make it available somewhere under your `WINEPREFIX` (I used `~/.wine/drive_c/`)
3. Run `wineconsole` to get a `cmd.exe`-like environment
4. From there, cd to whereever your shortcut.exe live and use it. Here's what I ran:

   ```
   Shortcut /a:c /f:"%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Desktop\Borderlands2.lnk" /t:"C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\Borderlands 2\Binaries\Win32\Borderlands2.exe"
   ```

If nothing else it has provided me with a renewed (and thoroughly deserved) hatred towards Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your user folder in ~/.wine/drive_c/users/ and to "Start Menu", "Programs" and copy the shortcut you want and paste it in ~/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Desktop/

You can create a launch shortcut in your linux with for example this command line:

wine explorer /desktop=arbname,1920x1080 "C:/Program Files/Windows NT/Accessories/wordpad.exe"

The wine window close when you close this wordpad but, if you reduce it, all the other wine software is accessible from the desktop.